# Bank statement or other proof of income uk visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am a 16 year old boy from albania and I want to apply for a UK standard visit visa to visit my cousin who is sponsoring for me. In the application UK visa web site is a question with alternatives [image: the visa web page]
As shown in the photo attached to this article what should be my answer considering that I am 16 and I don’t have any bank statements or any savings?
I have read somewhere that there is needed proof that you are not staying in uk after visa ends(this can be proved by bank statements from my parents and proof that I am still at high school)

Comment: You must provide some proof that you are the mean to travel in UK. Being a 16 year old, usually mean you need much less money. But you need some proof, e.g. from your father, if he sponsor you. BTW you should start thinking to have a bank account if you travel. ATM (or credit card) are handy, and simplify the process of booking (and being in hotels), and also of immigration. Often you should provide some deposit (and also at immigration you may show up that you have enough money).

Comment: But in my case my cousin who is a British citizen is the sponsor of my visit so how should I answer the question do you have any income?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi But in my case my cousin who is a British citizen is the sponsor for my trip so how should be the answer to the question do you have any income if I will answer no will this affect negatively for my visa to get approved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious first thing to say is that you should answer all the questions truthfully. Doing anything else will get you in trouble.

If somebody else is paying for your trip, and especially if you are a minor, then the questions about your personal financial circumstances are less significant. Instead the important questions are ones about your sponsor's finances, so that the visa officers can check the sponsor can afford your visit.

Assuming that you are living with your parents, and they are paying your living expenses, then you may also have to supply their financial statements to show that your cousin's paying for your visit is an appropriate thing to be doing. It would not make sense for your cousin to be paying for a short holiday in the UK if you were in fact unable to afford to live in your home country. Read carefully the guidance on the application.

The important thing with your parents finances is not whether they are earning more than your cousin, but whether they are earning enough to support you, and also that they have enough money to make your taking a vacation to the UK a sensible thing to do. For example, if your parents are not earning enough to cover your basic needs it does not make sense that your cousin would spend money on a vacation for you instead of giving you money to meet your basic needs.

Comment: And what happens if my parents don’t have such a good wage as my cousin in Britain has? Is there the possibility to refuse my visa? Thank you for your clear answer!

Comment: I added to the answer. And yes, there is always the possibility that your visa will be refused, whatever you do.